# changing name of "nomenclature" not working in lyx

Tags: lyx, nomenclature, preamble

why could it be that the suggested command won't work in Lyx? I am using the "Book (standard) class". Thank you, everyone!

```
\renewcommand\nomname{New Name for Nomenclature}
```

edit:

I have to enter the command in the Lyx' document settings in the preamble. I actually did not use the [\printnomenclature] command, but it's printed further down in the document.

once I convert it into a normal latex file, I can see that the lyx-generated nomenclature - entries are above my commands. (As Phelype suggested.) I don't know how to change this in Lyx, though.

```
%% LyX 2.3.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=3.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0bp}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{nomencl}
% the following is useful when we have the old nomencl.sty package
\providecommand{\printnomenclature}{\printglossary}
\providecommand{\makenomenclature}{\makeglossary}
\makenomenclature
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[light]{CormorantGaramond}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=footnotesize]{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{changepage}

%-----Literatur- und Siglenverzeichnis------
\renewcommand\nomname{Siglenverzeichnis}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This _should_ work as long as you use it _before_ `\printnomenclature`. If you are using that command (either version works) before the `\printnomenclature` and it still doesn't work, then please show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your document.

Comment: _Off-topic:_ Either `\renewcommand\nomname{...}` and `\renewcommand{\nomname}{...}` do the same because of how TeX grabs arguments. In _this case_ the `{...}` around the `\nomname` can be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I was finally able to solve the issue. Lyx apparently adds an automatic command regarding the name of the nomenclature *after* the preamble written by the user.

In order to change the name of the "nomenclature" you have to add the command

```
\renewcommand\nomname{New Name}
```

as a direct TeX-Code directly *in* the main document.
In order to add it to the toc, you also have to include

```
\def\nompreamble{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}
```

in the preamble.